# image quality while making thumbnail

Tags: php, thumbnails

i have this code for making proportional thumbnail :

```
function CroppedThumbnail($imgSrc,$thumbnail_width,$thumbnail_height) { //$imgSrc is a FILE - Returns an image resource.
//getting the image dimensions 
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imgSrc);  

if (strtolower(substr($imgSrc, -3)) == "jpg") {
    $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);
} else if (strtolower(substr($imgSrc, -3)) == "jpeg") {
    $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);
} else if (strtolower(substr($imgSrc, -3)) == "png") {

    $myImage = imagecreatefrompng($imgSrc);
} else if (strtolower(substr($imgSrc, -3)) == "gif") {
    $myImage = imagecreatefromgif($imgSrc);
}


$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($thumbnail_width/$thumbnail_height > $ratio_orig) {
   $new_height = $thumbnail_width/$ratio_orig;
   $new_width = $thumbnail_width;
} else {
   $new_width = $thumbnail_height*$ratio_orig;
   $new_height = $thumbnail_height;
}

$x_mid = $new_width/2;  //horizontal middle
$y_mid = $new_height/2; //vertical middle

$process = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_width), round($new_height));

imagecopyresampled($process, $myImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $process, 0, 0, ($x_mid-($thumbnail_width/2)), ($y_mid-($thumbnail_height/2)), $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);

imagedestroy($process);
imagedestroy($myImage);
return $thumb;
```

}

works good

but the quality of image is a little bit low

what should i do for increasing created picture quality

Comment: I 'm not sure what "a little bit low" means, but on another note you could fix the bug here: `else if (strtolower(substr($imgSrc, -3)) == "jpeg")`

Answer (score 1):

Have you set image quality, when saving result of this function?

This function, for example, lets you set jpeg compression, and default is quite low.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

If this is not the case, I might suggest dumping PHP GD altogether. It really is not best image manipulation library, just avaiable by default.
ImageMagick is great, but you will need to install it. Working with it gave me thumbnails which was smaller in filesize, but better in quality, than PHP GD ones.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bicubic interpolation during resize, consider using ImageMagick instead of GD, because its very CPU-intensive. For example here is [a post in russian](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111402/) (but you can see how complex code is)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the gif quality but if you using other image formats than remember to set the quality to 100. 
For example:imagepng($imageResource,NULL,100);